# Setup kafka-connect to fetch data from remote brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, remote-server, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set up Kafka connect sink connector. Kafka connect is part of Kafka connect worker (confluent-3.2.0). I have a Kafka broker (confluent-3.2.0)  up and running on machine A. I want to set up Kafka-connect-sink connector on another machine B to consume messages, using a custom Kafka-connect-sink connector jar. Assume that Kafka broker and Zoo keeper ports on machine A are open to machine B.

So should I install/setup confluent-3.2.0 on machine B (Since Kafka Connect is part of Kafka package) by setting the classpath to the Kafka-connect-sink connector jar and run the following command?

`./bin/connect-distributed.sh worker.properties`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you describe will work and is the easiest way to setup this system even though on machine B you really only need the start script, the configuration properties file, the jars for Kafka Connect, and the jars for the custom connector.